# objective-c memory management clarification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am trying to make a simple iphone app and I have been playing around with features and recently, delegates. I am just confused with regards to memory management because apparently "good code" makes my app crash with exc_bad_access.

I have an object with two data members and implementation empty for now.

```
@implementation semester: NSObject{
    NSInteger ID;
    NSString *name;
}
```

then my delegate method:

```
- (void) receiveSemester:(semester *)newSemester {
[test setText:newSemester.name];
}
```

and a view that is used as a form which has:

```
@interface addSemesterController : UIViewController {
id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
UITextField *txtName;
UILabel *prompt;
UIButton *ok;
UIButton *cancel;
}
```

all objects are made properties and synthesized in the application file. Here is the method that used the delegate:

```
- (IBAction) okClick:(id)sender{
// create semester object and return it
semester *created = [[semester alloc] init];
created.name = txtName.text;
[delegate receiveSemester:created];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And my dealloc method looks like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
/*
[txtName dealloc];
[prompt dealloc];
[ok dealloc];
[cancel dealloc];
 */
    [super dealloc];
}
```

With the deallocs of the objects contained in the form commented out, my app runs ok. However, when I uncomment them, I receive the exc_bad_access error in my delegate protocol:

```
// in main view controller
- (void) receiveSemester:(semester *)newSemester {
[test setText:newSemester.name];
    // test is a UILabel
}
```

I tried the zombie method and it says that the label calls a released object. I am not releasing my semester object in the "form" controller, and even if I was the delegate function is called before deallocating the view.

Clearly I should not be releasing the objects in the dealloc method, I am just unclear in the why I shouldn't.

Again, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: use [txtName release]; [prompt release]; [ok release]; [cancel release]; instead of dealloc and you can also work with ARC automatic reference counting..... with ARC you dont need to use dealloc, release, it will release memory automatically.... and you choose it in the starting when you create a new project, you can also change your project in ARC by Edit.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find the ARC option, where is it?

Comment: when you are create a new project - and at the window where you give your project name ..see below there are one option - "Use Automatic Reference Counting" just check this box...and then press next..

Comment: and if want to convert your old project in ARC - Edit - Refactor - Covert to objective C ARC - check your project and the press recheck - it will convert

Answer (score 2):

Use `release` to release the variables instead of calling `dealloc` on variables, due to this you are having issue -

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [txtName release];
    [prompt release];
    [ok release];
    [cancel release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: perfect! release doesn't make the app crash anymore. I am still unclear though. What is the difference between dealloc and release? And is releasing everything the proper way to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: Please, before you write any more code, [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Comment: @gamda- you need to check the documentation of basic memory management - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 0):

try writing

```
[txtName release];
[prompt release];
[ok release];
[cancel release];
```

instead of dealloc and these objects will be deallocated properly